# Cancel promise api request in angular 8 when enter to function

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, promise, angular-reactive-forms

i'm a little bit stucked.
i have a form with username input, which must be uniq.
so i bind to this input a class which fire call to the server and check input status (in use or not in use).
i wrapped everything with timeout (to let the user to write letters and then fire the request).

code:

```
static serverUniqueUserNameExists(authService: AuthService, timeout = 1500): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
        return new Observable((observer: Observer<ValidationErrors | null>) => {
            if (control.value.length == 0) {
                observer.next(null)
                observer.complete()
            } else {
                const clearTimer = setTimeout(async () => {
                    const res = await this.getUserNameStatus(authService, control)
                    if (res.status >= '400') {
                        observer.next({ error: true, serverError: true })
                    } else {
                        if (res.data.userExists) {
                            observer.next({ error: true, userNameAlreadyExist: true })
                        } else {
                            observer.next(null)
                            clearTimeout(clearTimer)
                        }
                    }
                    observer.complete()
                }, timeout)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

but when i look on the network i see that for every letter i type i fire a request to the server.

i need in some way to cancel all previous api calls that already fired and to fire only the **last** request.

cannot find any way for this.

someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

> You can create a simple `isFetching` state, to return whenever there
>   is request in progress. Recommend you to do on page side. Sample time add `denounce` in text input, so that it wont update with each char.

```
let isFetching = false
static serverUniqueUserNameExists(authService: AuthService, timeout = 1500): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
        if(isFetching) return Promise.resolve(null); // return from here
        return new Observable((observer: Observer<ValidationErrors | null>) => {
            if (control.value.length == 0) {
                observer.next(null)
                observer.complete()
            } else {
                const clearTimer = setTimeout(async () => {
                    /// code here
                    isFetching = false;
                    observer.complete()
                }, timeout)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

// Debounce Sample:

```
results$: Observable
    subject = new Subject()
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.results$ = this.subject.pipe(
            debounce(() => Rx.Observable.interval(1000)),
            map(searchText => this.httpClient.get("/api/search?q=" + searchText))
        )
    }
```

**More:** https://blog.bitsrc.io/3-ways-to-debounce-http-requests-in-angular-c407eb165ada

Comment: ok looks pretty good but in what way you declare isFetching = true ?

Comment: but in this way i always fire the first call without any way to cancel it, no ? 
if i got u its very good way but doesnt fire 1 request in Continuous typing. and as following it will not fire anything in the next 1500 ms, cuz we inizialize isFatching to true after the first call